# Current mirror circuit simple schematic

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image][image]

I know this is a current mirror circuit, which means that Io should be equal to Iref = 0.25 mA.

I made it in a simulation program and it shows that current only flows through the first transistor (from the left.) Why is that?

In the simulation program I connected Io to ground, because I didn't really know why it is 'floating' like that. Hope some of you might know.

Comment: Well Io flows from *the power supply* to the ground (which could be your VCC or another supply, that's one of the common uses for the mirror). So you should put a voltage supply with the + on the collector and read the current from it. The other terminal is correctly to th e ground. Can you post a screenshot of your simulation? Also, usually you see multiple output BJTs not multiple references… are you sure that's what you want? EDIT silly me, it's the transfer ratio

Comment: You have made a mistake - embed your simulation schematic.

Comment: Most likely you did not connect the bases of the other transistors. Do you see the dots?

Comment: 1) are you sure that the base connections of the 2nd and 3rd NPN are connected? 2) You need to apply a voltage to the collector of the NPN on the right (how else is current going to flow?) 3) It looks like you're using Falsted, which is limited (not sure if it can deal with NPNs in parallel properly), consider using LTSpice instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use LTSpice, I really tried to connect them properly but it doesn't work. After applying the voltage,can I just use Ohm's Law to find Io? Will it be around Iref?

Comment: Io will be 1/3 of Iref because you have 3 in parallel. Assuming all transistors are equal area devices.

Comment: The collector of Q1 needs to be connected to a voltage supply, possibly through a load. If left floating, Io will be 0. If the collector is grounded, Io might be negative, due to current flowing through the now forward biased base collector diode.

Comment: Common mistake using Falstad.  I know about it and it still gets me from time to time.  Connect each pin to another pin, not the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of the transistors are identical, since you have three diode-connected reference transistors in parallel, each will take approximately 1/3rd of the reference current.

As a result, you'll find \$I_\text{o} \approx \frac {1} {3} I_\text{ref}\$ as shown in this quick simulation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFN4YL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Those red dots are warnings, letting you know that there's no electrical connection there even though it looks like you may have meant for there to be one. So your circuit isn't actually what you think it is, and most of the transistors aren't actually connected.